# shutdown and systemd service

Tags: cron, systemd

At 5am cron runs shutdown, systemd executed /home/myuser/bin/mailme-shutdown.sh and my pc poweroff. When I startup the pc an email coming to me. The email is the script (mailme-shutodown.sh) executed before I powered up the pc. Any idea to send email before pc shutdown? I use local postfix with external smtp service.

```
cat /etc/crontab
00 05   * * *   root    /sbin/shutdown -h now


[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Requires=network.target
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/home/myuser/bin/mailme-startup.sh
ExecStop=/home/myuser/bin/mailme-shutdown.sh
User=myuser

[Install]
#WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=halt.target reboot.target shutdown.target

cat mailme-shutdown.sh

[...]
email=notification@gmail.com
echo "body" | mail -s "test" "$email"
[...]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should check if email was sent, and if current mail queue is empty then shutdown.
[How to verify if an email was successfully sent by postfix?](https://serverfault.com/questions/628506/how-to-verify-if-an-email-was-successfully-sent-by-postfix)

Comment: how. how tell shutdown that queue is empty?